# MacOS UI Freezes and Hangs after 10.14.6 (18G4032) Security Update

Tags: macos, safari, performance

I have updated my MacBook Air 2017 256GB model recently, the latest security patch 10.14.6 (18G4032).

I started to have random freezes. Sometimes, it goes back to normal after a few seconds. Sometimes, the computer is stuck completely and I can only hard-shutdown it, sometimes I get graphical glitches.

From my observations, this

1. happened since this security update
2. after adding some extensions to safari which I removed after first time freezing.

Any ideas what this could be and how I could solve this?

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue on my own mac, a 2017 iMac running 10.14.6. I get lots of temporary UI freezes throughout the day, though no graphical glitches and nothing that's required me to hard reboot. I reinstalled and am now downgraded to build 18G103 and am still getting the freezes. Have you ever managed to fix this, or have any idea which update caused the issue?

Comment: I upgraded it to Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2) and nothing freezes or hangs , I think problem is in the Mac OS Mojave.